# Why am i getting "Iresult" value right shifted?

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
    unsigned    int Iresult = 0x5500, Icount ;


    printf("before\n");
    for(Icount = 31; Icount != 0; Icount--)
    {
        printf("%d",( (Iresult >> Icount) & 1) );
    }

        printf("%d",( (Iresult >> 0) & 1) );
    printf("\n");

    Iresult =   ( ( (unsigned char *) &Iresult )[1] << 1  ) ;

    printf("after\n");
    for(Icount = 31; Icount != 0; Icount--)
    {
        printf("%d",( (Iresult >> Icount) & 1) );
    }
        printf("%d",( (Iresult >> 0) & 1) );
    printf("\n");


}
```

**output :**
before

```
00000000000000000101010100000000
```

after

```
00000000000000000000000010101010
```

here i am performing a left shift of 2nd byte in Iresult.

why am i getting a right shift output if i perform a left shift`

Comment: Your question is not clear enough.

Comment: Are you able to understand the code?

Answer (score 0):

You take the pointer to the `unsigned int` named `Iresult` and cast it into a pointer to `unsigned char`. Using that pointer you read the *second* `unsigned char` and shift it left by 1.

I think you're not aware that your machine uses [little endian encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), and that `[1]` indexes the second entry.

That's why the second byte with the value of 0x55 is shifted left by 1, giving 0xAA. This is what you see in the output.

Answer (score 0):

> here i am performing a left shift of 2nd byte in Iresult.

This is wrong. You do not simply perform a left shift of 2nd byte.

```
Iresult =   ( ( (unsigned char *) &Iresult )[1] << 1  ) ;
```

What you do is

- Take second byte (0x55)
- Left shift by 1 (0xAA)
- Assign the resultung (unsigned char) to Iresult

During the assignment the value ends up in lowest 8 bits of the variable.
Therefore you do not get `0x0000AA00` but `0x000000AA`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not right shifted. Here `Iresult =   ( ( (unsigned char *) &Iresult )[1] << 1  ) ;` you chose to only copy byte 1. It will be stored at the most least significant address of `Iresult`.

If you wanted the 2 least significant bytes, you'd have to do something like this instead:

```
Iresult = (unsigned int)((unsigned char*)&Iresult)[0] | 
          (unsigned int)((unsigned char*)&Iresult)[1]<<8;
```